# Combining 2 different size lists in C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a 2 Lists. I want to combine them into 1 List.

The problem is one of the two lists is only one count size

firstList.Count = 1

While the second list is the size of two:

secondList.Count = 2

So I want to combine bot of these lists into 1 List.

```
megaList => firstList {0, Empty},
            secondList {0 , 2}
```

My code to do this wont work because the two lists are not of the same size. How do I fix this?

```
 List<QuestionAndResponses> megaList = new List<QuestionAndResponses>();
                for (var i = 0; i < firstList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    megaList.Add(new QuestionAndResponses()
                    {
                        Responses = new List<Response>(firstList[i].Response),
                        Questions = new List<Question>(secondList[i].Questions)
                    });
                }
```

My Model looks like so:

```
public class QuestionAndResponses
    {
        public PreScreener Question { get; set; }
        public PreScreenerResponse Response { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to see for the result?

Comment: I want QuestionAndResponses List to have both the firstList and the secondList in it. In other words combining the two arrays into one larger array.

Comment: What business logic governs how to correlate responses with questions?  In other words, do responses know which question they belong to?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know why you have these two lists and what you want to store there. But with only simple changes to your code, why you don't just loop through the larger list?

```
List<QuestionAndResponses> megaList = new List<QuestionAndResponses>();
var biggerList = firstList.Count() > secondList.Count() ? firstList : secondList
for (var i = 0; i < biggerList.Count(); i++)
{
   var response = firstList.Count() >= i+1 ? new List<Response>(firstList[i].Response) : new List<Response>();
   var questions = secondList.Count() >= i+1 ? new List<Question>(secondList[i].Questions) : new List<Question>(); 

   megaList.Add(new QuestionAndResponses()
      {
         Responses = response,
         Questions = questions
      });
}
```

Hope this is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I think your model might be wrong, but you will know this better than me. Do the responses in the first array belong to the same question? Can one question have more than one response? In that case, your model could be:

```
public class QuestionAndResponses
{
   public PreScreener Question {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable <PreScreenerResponse> Responses {get; set;}
}

var questionAndResponses = new List<QuestionAndResponses>();
foreach (var question in secondList)
{
   questionAndResponses.Add(
            new QuestionAndResponses
           {
              Question = question,
              Responses = firstList.Where(f => f.QuestionId = question.QuestionId)
           });
}
```

Just throwing it out there...